# Bitwise & in javascript not returning the expected result

Tags: javascript, bitwise-and

I am working on BitWise AND operator in javascript.

I have two 32 bit nunber

```
4294901760 (11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000) and

4294967040 (11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000)
```

when I and them bitwise  `4294901760 & 4294967040` I got -65536 as a result although the result should be `4294901760`.

Can any one please guide me am I missing something? Or what is the correct way to do it.
Thanks

Comment: can you share with us your javascript code that does the `&` operation?

Comment: console.log(4294901760 & 4294967040); this is complete code :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
console.log((4294901760 & 4294967040) >>> 0);
```

Append `>>> 0` to have it interpret your operation as unsigned.

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/JamZw/

**More info:**
[Bitwise operations on 32-bit unsigned ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798111/bitwise-operations-on-32-bit-unsigned-ints)

Answer (score 1):

Operands of bitwise operations in javascript are [converted to **signed** 32 bit integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Signed_32-bit_integers). Unsigned `4294901760` has same binary representation as signed `-65536`. 
You can use `>>> 0` to convert result of `&` to unsigned, eg:

```
(4294901760 & 4294967040) >>> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this custom implementation of AND bitwise operation:

```
function and(a, b){
    a = a.toString(2).split('');
    b = b.toString(2).split('');
    var length = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
    function padZeroes(array, size){
        while(array.length <= size ){
            array.unshift('0');
        }
    }
    padZeroes(a, length);
    padZeroes(b, length);
    var result = [];
    $.each(a, function(i, v){
        result.push((a[i]==b[i] && a[i]!='0')?'1':'0');
    });
    var r = parseInt(result.join(''), '2');
    return r;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pqpK/)