# Overflow when using Left Shift (<<)VS Multiplication (*)

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I was recently doing a [bit manipulation problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/concatenation-of-consecutive-binary-numbers/) where I was required to left shift a large number. My initial idea was to simply use the left shift operator and write `num << i` where `i` is the number of bits I want to shift. Easy enough.

The difficulty came when I attempted to shift numbers that were quite large. In these instances my answer came out to be wrong. So I started looking at other peoples answer to this problem and saw many others using `num * (2 ** i)` instead of `num << i`.

I understand how these two accomplish the same thing on smaller inputs, but fail to understand why one seems to cause overflow with larger values of `num` whereas the other is fine. What is the reasoning here?

When `num` is small, they yield the same answer.

```
const i = 4;
const num = 1234;

num * (2 ** i)  // 19744
num << i        // 19744
```

When `num` is large the shift operator overflows.

```
const i = 4;
const num = 462911488;

num * (2 ** i)  // 7406583808
num << i        // -1183350784
```

And does this mean I am never better off always using `<<` since it has overflow issues?

Comment: Potential duplicate of [Left shift results in negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030623/left-shift-results-in-negative-numbers-in-javascript)?

Comment: Well, not quite. I understand why left shifting a big number causes an overflow - we run out of our 32 bits. What I don't understand is why `num * (2 ** i)` doesn't overflow.

Comment: Bitwise operators convert their operands to 32-bit integers, but JavaScript numbers are double-precision floating-point numbers and arithmetic operations such as multiplication and exponentiation don't convert their operands to 32-bit integers.

Comment: Realize this is a dated question, but one can make use of BigInt and not run into this limitation.  Also, if 64 bits is sufficient, one can use BigUint64Array elements...